# Using Cast in SQL to convert text data to integer, to take AVG

Tags: sql, casting, integer, average, currency

I need to take the average of this data set but the column is formatted as money/text.

[image: data that needs converting]

I have tried:

```
SELECT
    sfo_calendar.calender_date,
    AVG(CAST(sfo_calendar.price AS int) avg_price
FROM
    sfo_calendar
GROUP BY sfo_calendar.calender_date;
```

Yet keep getting this error:

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "$101.00"
SQL state: 22P02

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the $ sign, it is not convertible to int so you can try replacing that by zero since it is in the beginning of the price and won't affect the value.

```
    SELECT
        sfo_calendar.calender_date,
        AVG(CAST(replace(sfo_calendar.price,'$',0) AS int) avg_price
    FROM
        sfo_calendar
    GROUP BY sfo_calendar.calender_date;
```